# How to get Unconsumed message count

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Hello I am integrating Twilio on android and I need to display unconsumed message count with the channel name below is my code snippet but every time I'm getting count zero(0) please help me

```
channel.getUnconsumedMessagesCount(new CallbackListener<Long>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Long aLong) {
    unreadCountTextView.setText(String.valueOf(aLong));
}
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Looks like you might have to set a Consumption Horizon on a channel--Chat does not automatically do that for you. From the [docs on `Consumption Horizon`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/consumption-horizon), *"If a user does not have a Consumption Horizon set on a channel, getting unconsumed messages will always return 0."*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had already read the same document, I can see consumption horizon as 10sec(default) value. I had checked all option REACHABILITY ENABLED, MESSAGE READ STATUS, CONSUMPTION REPORT TIMEOUT as 10 but then also when sender send a message on receiver side channel list is automatically updated based on the last message arrive at respected channel but every time I'm getting the unconsumed message as zero(0)

Comment: Is there any other way to set unconsumed message horizon when sending a message from sender side so the receiver will get unconsumed message count

Comment: You need to actually set the horizon on the receiver side, you can start with setting `setNoMessagesConsumed()` on a channel when the user joins it and then updating when they scroll messages into view. The 10 second value is how often the batches of consumption horizon updates are sent, but you have to queue up that update yourself.

Answer (score 0):

According to new Twilio Conversation API, progress listener is now gone so, you could calculate count in this way:

> This code would work if you have only one channel or multiple channels so, it would return count of all conversation unconsummed messages.

> Kotlin:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
      val messageChannel = Channel<Int>()
      val allChannels = (get my conversation from conversationClient)
      allChannels?.let { item ->
              item.forEach { channel ->
                   // Get unconsummed message count
                   channel.getUnreadMessagesCount { count ->
                        count?.let { no ->
                              launch {messageChannel.send(no.toInt())}
                        }
                   }
               }
       
                //Observe channel to assure that above callbacks returned data
                var msgsCount = 0
                val messageReceive = launch {
                         repeat(item.size) {
                               msgsCount += messageChannel.receive()
                         }
                }
                messageReceive.join()
     
                log.i("Total message count", msgsCount) 
      }
 }
```